# Register Subkey to automatically open dwg file

Tags: windows, cmd, registry

I want to automatically open DWG file so I need to add DWG subkey on `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\AttachmentExecute]` but I don't know what subkey name for dwg file.

I already add `Excel.Sheet.8` subkey to automatically open excel file and it's works perfectly

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command-line command [`assoc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/assoc) "*displays or modifies file name extension associations.*".

For example, running `assoc .xls` at a cmd prompt returns `.xls=Excel.Sheet.8`. The same way, `assoc .dwg` will return the type associated with `.dwg` files, provided one was registered.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but file extension for .dwg is not found , maybe I can use  this command assoc .dwg=xxxx but I don't know associations for .dwg. I already installed DWG trueview software

Comment: @gpong Is the app associated with `.dwg` files, or does it come with an option to associate itself with `.dwg` files? The `AttachmentExecute` key does not define the system-wide association, it only uses existing associations for [`IAttachmentExecute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-iattachmentexecute) purposes.